# In Microsoft Word, how can I insert a section break that doesn't take up any space?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Microsoft Word, how can I insert a section break that doesn't take up any space? So far my Section Break (continuous) takes up one line of space.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `Draft view` using the button near the 100% in the bottom right corner (hover over the buttons to see what they do).

This will show you the document formatting including the section breaks. You can now select and format them as you would with anything else in the document. Modify the `Paragraph` settings to suppress the space after the section break.

Set up a new style for section breaks if you need this more than once.